# Universal Sonic Mouth

Tags: shrinkwrap

I've been following a tutorial for sonic's mouth.It allows for universal movement across another object using shrinkwrap.
It seems that I've ran into some problems.I can't get it to work how it does in the tutorial.
Can anyone help me?
Tutorial:https://blenderartists.org/t/universal-sonic-mouth-blender-rigging-tutorial/1444352
I'll give the file I've been testing this with here.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the whole tutorial but this bone (called *Position*) is not supposed to deform the lips, the tutorial says it can deform slightly around the lips, but its main goal is actually to control the lips bones:

[image]

You also need to correct the lips bones weight, it's very low:

[image]

So maybe what you should do is first disable the *Deform* option of the bones that are not supposed to deform the mouth, parent the mouth to the other bones With *Automatic Weights* (or manually assign), then enable the *Deform* option again for the first bones and paint (or manually assign) to the wanted vertex group:

[image]